# Как организовать хранение бинарной системы маркетинга?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Вкратце — необходимо хранить информацию о том, кто кого пригласил. Для ясности прикладываю скриншот:
<img src="http://savepic.su/3935661.jpg" alt="image"/>

Нужно организовать хранение этой информации в БД MySQL и последующий вывод в PHP. Самая важная часть — нужно по запросу показывать "размер" команды каждого из участников. Например, для участника 2 — это 7 человек (он сам + участники 4 5 8 9 10 11). Для участника 5 — 3 человека (он сам + участники 10 11).

Подскажите, как лучше организовать хранение такой информации в БД и последующую выборку в PHP.

Пока идея следующая. В таблице `relationships` храним две колонки:
1. id_user (id пользователя)
2. id_curator (кто его пригласил)

Например:
id_user = 2
id_curator = 1

Но как тогда организовать вывод информации о численности команды?

Спасибо.

Comment: рекурсивная выборка из бд.

Comment: Nested Sets

Comment: Кто кого пригласил или кто под кем стоит в матрице надо хранить? Точнее это рабочая матрица или только страница, на которой показывается команда участника?